# Kinetic energy of fluid + collision

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy

When a fluid is flowing, it has of course a kinetic energy and thus we can define kinetic power equal to ρAv v is the velocity and A is the surface of a solid for example. I have a question (maybe it is a strange one) : When fluid collides with a solid, do all the molecules collide with the solid or some of them or we cannot know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for yourself.

Just pour 2 cups of water into a (tall) glass.
Then pour a third cup with some food coloring mixed in.

You can see that only a small amount of the food coloring gets to the bottom before stopping.

Comment: I am talking about the quantity pAv when it is colliding with a turbine for example

Comment: @Tonylb1: Still, it's a fluid. Every molecule of the fluid doesn't have to bounce off the blade. Some do, and then the others bounce off them.

Comment: Ok but it affects the quantity of energy received by the solid or no? More molecules bounces on the blade more energy or it is like a collision between 2 solids?

Comment: @Tonylb1: Suppose have a stack of two 1kg boxes piled up. You grab the bottom box and lift the stack. How much force does it take? 2kg, right? Did the top box touch your hand? No. You lifted it *through* the bottom box. Gasses are the same way. Molecule A bounces off the surface. Then it bounces off B, then back, etc. Check out [*Newton's cradle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cradle).